# Ubuntu freezes after "Saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned" during boot

Tags: boot

After I have installed Panteon DE and rebooted, my OS does not continiues the boot process after showing following:

> Saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned

It just displays bootsplash ad infinitum. How can I fix the issue?